# How to invalidate $http call with cache:true when header changes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-http

I'm fetching a remote resource and caching the result:

```
$http({
    method:'GET',
    cache:true,
    url:'...'
});
```

This works fine. However, when the user changes the languge in the UI, I also change the `Accept-Language` header on all AJAX calls.

The problem is caching is done based on URL so if a call is made using `en-US` as `Accept-Language` that gets cached and any other calls, regardless of language, are served from cache.

I don't want to add the language to the URL.

What are my options?

Comment: have a look at `$cacheFactory` and wrap it in a little service that you can invalidates cache when the user language changes. Sorry, not a proper answer because I haven't got any sample code: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory

Comment: That's a good idea. I could also try to decorate `$cacheFactory`. Thanks, Jorg.

Comment: You could post that as answer, it doesn't have to have code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$cacheFactory` can be used to invalidate cache when the user changes language. You could try to decorate it, or use wrap it in a service perhaps